# Open files with different options

Tags: matlab, file

I have two sets of files:

Set 1: { reactant.1.h.txt, reactant.2.h.txt, reactant.3.h.txt }

Set 2: { no2conc.txt, so2conc.txt, coconc.txt }

I am able to open each of them by using

```
reactanct_1 = fopen('reactant.1.h.txt','r');
no2_conc = fopen('no2conc.txt','r');
```

Indeed the "1", "2" and "3" in Set 1 refer to NO2, SO2 and CO in Set 2.

I want to write a function such that if I input NO2 into the function, it will open the two specific files in two sets.

So, I design as:

```
function openfile(chemical)

switch chemical
      case NO2
          id = 1; % for the use of set 1
          string = 'no2'; % for the use of set2
      case SO2
          id = 2; % for the use of set 1
          string = 'so2'; % for the use of set2
      case CO
          id = 2; % for the use of set 1
          string = 'co'; % for the use of set2
end
```

However, I give a trial that %d refers to my chemicals id and $s refers to the chemical names:

```
reactanct = fopen('reactant.%d.h.txt', id, 'r');
conc = fopen('%sconc.txt', string,'r');
```

But matlab returns me `Error using fopen`.

I appreciate for your help.

Comment: `string` is a built-in function, don't use it as a variable name. Maybe that already helps.

Comment: @thewaywewalk thanks but I change with another name but it still cannot open the files.

Comment: do you enter strings like `'SO2'` or without quotes `SO2`?

Comment: What error is shown?

Comment: @ thewaywewalk I have used single quotes but it returns `Error using fopen
Invalid permission.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with how you're passing the filenames to [`fopen`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html). From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fopen.html), the (optional) second input to `fopen` needs to be the file access type, here you have it defined as your chemical ID and chemical name.

You should be able to fix this with a [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) call to generate your filename:

```
function openfile(chemical)

switch chemical
      case NO2
          id = 1; % for the use of set 1
          mychem = 'no2'; % for the use of set2
      case SO2
          id = 2; % for the use of set 1
          mychem = 'so2'; % for the use of set2
      case CO
          id = 2; % for the use of set 1
          mychem = 'co'; % for the use of set2
end

reactanct = fopen(sprintf('reactant.%d.h.txt', id), 'r');
conc = fopen(sprintf('%sconc.txt', mychem), 'r');
```

Comment: @ excaza Thanks. it works with one more modification by using `num2str(id)`.

Comment: @nam The conversion is unnecessary, `sprintf` already does it internally.

Comment: @excaze oh yes, maybe I have wrongly used `%s` in `reactanct = fopen(sprintf('reactant.%d.h.txt', id), 'r');`. Thanks again.